# Insert html tags to svg

Tags: jquery, highcharts, append

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("svg g.highcharts-button").before("<hr/>");    
});
```

Is it possible to append a div or any html tag to 'svg' which creating by highchart graph library.

Comment: What is the purpose of pushing that tags? Could you desribe your goal in more details?

Comment: Need to add a line between legend area & Export button (button moved to bottom right).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/0ok3o77e/

Comment: Instaed of that, use a [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path) to add a line.